# Passing input properties over angular component with css class selector

Tags: angular5, angular-components, angular2-components

I have a component with class selector. popup is component with css class selector '.popup'

```
<div class="popup">
  My Content
</div>
```

I want to pass some input and output properties over it, for example, just like with normal component selector

```
<div class='popup' [open]="open" (afterclose)="afterclose">
</div>
```

But I get error -  `Can't bind to 'open' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.`

My Component:-

```
@Component({
  selector: '.popup',
  templateUrl: './popup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./popupx.component.scss']
})

export class PopupComponent {
  @Input() open:boolean;
  @Output() afterClose: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
}
```

How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Because you try to send data to div.
Name your component and pass data to it, for example:

```
<popup [open]="open"></popup>
```

Comment: I dont want this way, i i know this already, i want to use it as a class.

Comment: Please see the selector -   selector: '.popup',

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a popup component, create a popup directive and use it on DIV. Then you will be able to use the inputs and outputs defined.

Comment: Thanks, i will try that.